# grails domain class not mocked

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I'm trying to mock the Role class generated by shiro plugin in a Grails 2.2.1 app. When i'm runnint the unit test I'm getting this error that looks like the dynamics method are not added.

This is the Role class:

```
class Role {
    String name

    static hasMany = [ users: User, permissions: String ]

    static belongsTo = User

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    } 
}
```

and this is the unit test:

```
@TestFor(UserService) 
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
@Mock([User, Role])
class UserServiceTests {
    void testSaveFacebookUser(){ 
        //given
        def adminRole = new Role(name: RoleEnum.ADMIN.name)
        adminRole.addToPermissions("*:*")
        adminRole.save()
    }
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
Running 1 unit test... 1 of 1
Failure:  testSaveFacebookUser(a4o.services.UserServiceTests)
  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: a4o.Role.addToPermissions() is applicable 
  for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [*:*]
```

**UPDATE**

found this on JIRA, but it says it was closed for 2.0.4 http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8779 . Maybe it's open again.

Comment: Are you unit testing the `domain` or a `service`? I think if it is service, then `@TestFor` is sufficient, you do not need the `@TestMixin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to grails 2.2.2 solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `hasMany` statement is supposed to be used to connect the given class with other Grails domain classes, not with other object. If you need to save a list of permissions as String objects, you need to create (and handle!) that list of strings outside the hasMany block; something like this:

```
class Role {
    String name

    List<String> permissions 

    static hasMany = [ users: User ]

    static belongsTo = User

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    } 
}
```

Anyways, my suggestion is not to reinvent the wheel and use the [sprint security plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) (or another one of your choice).

Comment: well, in my case the shiro security plugin is more suited... this is the Role class generated by the plugin. I made the modification you suggested but i get the same error and the error says the dynamic method is missing